# In LLSE $e_i$ are orthogonal random variables

Tags: regression, least-squares, descriptive-statistics

If we have a sequence of zero-mean random variables $(y_0,y_1,...,y_{i-1})$ and 
$$e_i =y_i-\hat{y}_{i|i-1},\ \ \&\ \ \ \hat{y}_{0|-1}=0 $$
$\hat{y}_{i|i-1}=$ LLSE (Linear least square estimate) of $y_i$ given $(y_0,y_1,...,y_{i-1})$.

It is required to show that the $e_i$ are orthogonal random variables.

My approach: We know that if two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal then
$$\textbf{E}\left[XY^*\right]=0$$ Then we can show
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}\left[e_ie_j^*\right]&=\textbf{E}\left[(y_i-\hat{y}_{i|i-1})(y_j-\hat{y}_{j|j-1})^*\right] \\
&=\textbf{E}[y_iy_j^*]-\textbf{E}[y_i\hat{y}_{j|j-1}^*]-\textbf{E}[\hat{y}_{i|i-1}y_j^*]+ \hat{y}_{i|i-1}\hat{y}_{j|j-1}^* \\
&=\textbf{E}[y_iy_j^*]+\hat{y}_{i|i-1}\hat{y}_{j|j-1}^*
\end{align*}

......
I am kind of stuck at this point of how to conclude that it boils down to 0.

I will be glad if someone can give some insights on this.

Can we use Gram-Schmidt to solve this problem??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you should substitute estimations, i.e. $y_{i|i-1}$; otherwise you can't go anywhere from here because LLSE uses orthogonality. To find the orthogonality, you need to use LLSE. Check out https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Orthogonality_principle

Comment: @gunes What should i substitute $\hat{y}_{i|i-1}$ with? Should it be $\hat{y}_{i|i-1} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{i-1} y_i \theta_i$

Comment: That is a linear estimator, but since we're talking about the LLSE, you should also substitute $\theta_i$